Не получается корректно сделать миграцию с MySql django


введите сюда описание изображения

Когда пытаюсь сделать миграцию, выводит это:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:         
'django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend 
or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one 
of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where 
XXX is one of:
'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Вроде, всё сделал: заранее создал базу данных, подключил PyMySql и настроил его в __init__. Правильно настроил settings - в чем еще может быть причина?

А так, когда локальный сервер запускаете, ошибок не выдаёт? Может миграции снести, хотя вряд ли это решит проблему, просто единственное, что на ум пришло

Проблема с mysqlclient или PyMySQL. Либо подключено что-то не так, либо проверьте виртуальное окружение.

@капибара Проблема решена, но спасибо за помощь)

Проблема была в том, что cmd Windows в принице не воспринимает почему-то PyMySql, и из-за этого была данная ошибка. При работе в PowerShell проблем уже не было.
